# How to move element front and back?

Tags: javascript, raphael

DEMO:[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mzwgkLmx/)

I am using `raphael js` in my application. Here I need to re-arrange element order on paper. I want to move back or front element one place at a time. I tried Using `toFront()` and `toBak()`, but it moves to the end or top of paper. I just want to move 1 position.

**UPDATE:** I am trying to find a solution for, overlapping elements. I mean Suppose I add 2 elements on paper and drag 1 element over another element. Than is there way to find that second element is over element 1.

e.g-> suppose I have `Rect, circle, rect2` in my paper. I want to move `rect2` to the position of `circle` and  vise versa. I am not getting a way to do this in `RaphaelJS. There are two methods,`element.prev`and`element.nex`t. I tried using them, but not able to understand how to use them.
CODE:

```
<b>Click on rectangle</b>
                <div  id="editor"></div>
<button type = "button" onclick="moveBack()" >Back
```

JS:

```
var paper = Raphael("editor", 635,500),
        canvas= document.getElementById('editor').style.backgroundColor='gray';
r1 = paper.rect(80,40,250,80,5)
r2 = paper.rect(180,80,290,80,5)
r3 = paper.rect(120,140,200,80,5)

r1.attr({
         fill:'red',
    });
r2.attr({
         fill:'blue',
    });
r3.attr({
         fill:'green',
    });
ft= paper.freeTransform(r1,{draw:['bbox'],
            rotate: true,keepRatio:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],
            scale:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides' ]});
ft= paper.freeTransform(r2,{draw:['bbox'],
            rotate: true,keepRatio:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],
            scale:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides' ]});
ft= paper.freeTransform(r3,{draw:['bbox'],
            rotate: true,keepRatio:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],
            scale:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides' ]});

 var moveBack = function () {
r2.toBack();
}
```

Comment: Tried insertAfter/Before ? http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.insertAfter

Comment: @Ian I tried it to.. but no luck..

Comment: @Ian Got it.. Can you post your comment as answer.. So that I can accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Raphaels insertBefore and insertAfter to get to the right position.

element.insertAfter( otherEl );

[doc](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.insertAfter)

Comment: No idea unless you say. Open a new question if its not closely related maybe.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution for, overlapping elements. I mean Suppose I add 2 element on paper and drag 1 elemnt over another element. Than is there way to find that 2 element is over element 1.

Comment: I'd ask that as a new question with a concise example.

Comment: sure. I am putting this as question.